# Reference proof from Zarantonello's 1960 Article

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, nonlinear-analysis

I cannot find anywhere an online version or reference proof of Zarantonello's 1960 article: E. H. Zarantonello. Solving functional equations by contractive averaging.
Math. Research Center Report, 160, 1960."

In particular, I'm looking for his prove of a generalized Lax-Milgram theorem where we weaken the assumptions from bounded linear to Lipschitz-monotone.

Comment: Have you tried IIL at your institute?